# Inclined Plane Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a simple picture of an box on top of an inclined plane plus a rough horizontal plane, like in the figure below.

[image: My objective]

I have finally written the following code taking inspiration from [this link](https://latexdraw.com/free-body-diagram-of-an-inclined-plane-in-tikz/) and Zarko's answer and comments:

```latex
    \begin{figure}
    %Inclined Plane, horizontal plane
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

            \def\ang{150}

            % Inclined plane
            \draw (0,0) coordinate[pos=1.,label={[above=1mm]{B}}] (B)  -- ++ (\ang:5) coordinate[label=above left:A] (A) |- (B) coordinate[pos=0.5] (O);


            % Angle Theta on the background wrt the inclined plane
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                \pic [draw, thick, -, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.35, fill=gray!30, angle radius=10mm] {angle=A--B--O};
            \end{scope}

            % Horizontal plane
            \draw   (B) -- node[below=2mm] {$\mu$} ++ (3,0) coordinate[label=right:C] (aux);
            \path   [pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={2pt},
                  line width=0.1pt]},
                  pattern color=gray]  (B) rectangle ++ (3,-0.2);
            
        
            % h
            \draw (O) -- node[midway,left=2mm] {$h$} (A);


            % Mass
            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
                \node (M) [draw=black,
                fill=yellow!60,
                minimum width=0.5cm,
                minimum height=0.5cm,
                anchor=north east,
                rotate=\ang,
                label=south west:$m$] at (A) {};
            \end{scope}

            % Speed in A, v_A
            \draw[thick, -{Triangle[]}] (M.center) -- ++ (\ang:-1) node[above right] {$\vec{v}_A$};

 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Setting of problem \ref{prob: inclined_plane_pm_I}.}
    \label{fig: inclined_plane_pm_I}
\end{figure}
```

which is reasonably good for my taste. I haven't dealt with the curly brace next to the *h*, but I'm happy to do away with it for now.

[image: good attempt]

Many thanks to Zarko and Jasper.

Comment: Welcome to TeX: SE! Float doesn't work in `standalone` ...

Comment: I am actually using {book}, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As for 1): The line is thinner, because the gray area covers half of the width of the line. You can draw the line again or you can place the gray area below the line.

Comment: It seems that will be helpful to read some introductory text about LaTeX. For example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf. BTW, just one problem  in question ... and received answer solve your problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**
Ups, positioning of coordinate A was wrong (instead of absolute should be relative ...)

Like this?

[image]

In comparison to your MWE I made the following changes:

- use `arrows.meta` library
- where needed use relative coordinate
- corners labels are write as labels in coordinate
- square on the top is rotated by use `rotate around`
- for fun is marked right angle at `C`

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                decorations.pathmorphing,             
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                patterns.meta, 
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    ANG/.style = {draw, 
                  angle radius = 12mm,
                  angle eccentricity=1.2},
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour={#3}},
      N/.style = {draw, fill=orange!30, minimum size=11mm,
                  anchor=south west}
                     ]
\def\Ang{150}
\draw[red,pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={2pt},
                   line width=0.1pt]},
                   pattern color=gray] 
            (3.5,0)  coordinate[label=below:B] (b) -- ++   % <---
            (\Ang:5) coordinate[label=above left:A] (a) |-
            (b)      coordinate[pos=0.5, label=below:C] (c);
\pic [ANG, "$\theta$"]  {angle = a--b--c};
\pic [draw, angle eccentricity=.5, "$\cdot$"]
            {right angle = b--c--a};                  % <--- added for fun
%
\draw[BC=8pt/ /teal] (c) -- node[left=4mm] {$h$} (a);
\node[N, rotate around={330:(a)}] at (a) {}; 
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Regarding your comment:

- for fill angle locus you only need add to`ANG` style options `fill=<desired color>` .
- for example

```
    ANG/.style = {draw, fill=gray!30,  
                  angle radius = 12mm,
                  angle eccentricity=0.75},
```

[image]

For fun one more option, with `ANG` locus on background (by this is preserved thickens triangle border lines):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                backgrounds,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                patterns.meta,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    ANG/.style = {draw, fill=gray!30,  
                  angle radius = 12mm,
                  angle eccentricity=0.75},
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour={#3}},
      N/.style = {draw, fill=orange!30, minimum size=11mm,
                  anchor=south west}
                     ]
\def\Ang{150}
\draw[red,pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={2pt},
                   line width=0.1pt]},
                   pattern color=gray]
            (3.5,0)  coordinate[label=below:B] (b) -- ++   % <---
            (\Ang:5) coordinate[label=above left:A] (a) |-
            (b)      coordinate[pos=0.5, label=below:C] (c);
\scoped[on background layer]
\pic [ANG, "$\theta$"]  {angle = a--b--c};
\pic [draw, angle eccentricity=.5, "$\cdot$"]
            {right angle = b--c--a};                  % <--- added for fun
%
\draw[BC=8pt/ /teal] (c) -- node[left=4mm] {$h$} (a);
\node[N, rotate around={330:(a)}] at (a) {};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

- What you ask in comment and edited question, is not hard to add, however it may require to look  in `TikZ & PGF manual`.
- In the third part of Ti*k*Z / PGF manual (Ti*k*Z ist *kein* Zeichenprogramm) is described all what you need to know for this. Very worth to read it!
- Regarding your request, hopefully the following MWE should fulfil your expectation:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                backgrounds,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                patterns.meta,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    ANG/.style = {draw, fill=gray!30,
                  angle radius = 12mm,
                  angle eccentricity=0.75},
    BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour={#3}},
      N/.style = {draw, fill=orange!30, minimum size=11mm,
                  anchor=south west}
                     ]
\def\Ang{150}
\draw[red]  (3.5,0)  coordinate[label=above right:B] (b) -- ++   % <---
            (\Ang:5) coordinate[label=above left:A] (a) |-
            (b)      coordinate[pos=0.5] (c);
\scoped[on background layer]
\pic [ANG, "$\theta$"]  {angle = a--b--c};
\pic [draw, angle eccentricity=.5, "$\cdot$"]
            {right angle = b--c--a};                  % <--- added for fun
%
\draw[BC=8pt/ /teal] (c) -- node[left=4mm] {$h$} (a);
\node[N, rotate around={330:(a)}] at (a) {};
% new
\draw   (b) -- node[below=2mm] {$\mu$} ++ (3,0) coordinate[label=right:$C$] (aux);
\path   [pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={2pt},
                  line width=0.1pt]},
                  pattern color=gray]  (b) rectangle ++ (3,-0.2);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see now the difference between absolute/relative coordinates. If I wanted to draw the arc $\theta$ by filling it in gray, how would I do it?

Comment: @espoma, accordingly extend definition of `\ANG` style . See edited answer where I assume that `\theta` is inside angle locus.

Comment: Thanks - I've made some progress, see the edited question. Still have some doubts though.

Comment: The gray area seems to cover half of the width of the red lines rendering them a tad thinner.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, yes. If you like to preserve width of red lines, then angle should be drawn on background layer as is done in the example before last.